# How to include more than one .css file in ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, css

I would like to have two .css files. One for each master\content page and one file for common elements. How to do this?

The following code doesn't work (css classes from Common.css file are not avalaible)

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link href="MasterPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
    <link href="Common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />     
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="Master_Header" CssClass="SomeClassFromCommonCssFile"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the styles from MasterPage.css are applied and the ones from Common.css aren't, my first guess would be that the two css files aren't in the same folder. Or you mistyped one of the filenames.

Comment: What do you mean by *css classes from Common.css file are not avalaible*?

Comment: @Kristof I haven't misstyped them and they are in the same folder, otherwise Visual Studio would mark the link as unavalaible. @Darin, I mean that a given class which I've created in Common.css file is not visible under code complete of visual studio when I am starting to write CssClass= and the styles from the file are not applied to my page.

Comment: Are you sure styles defined in MasterPage.css _are_ applied? Try prefixing the paths to the stylesheets with a / like this: <link href="/MasterPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
    <link href="/Common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> or, if they are in some kind of folder: <link href="/some/folder/MasterPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
    <link href="/some/folder/Common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: @Kristof I am sure, I am doing heavy div styling in MasterPage.css, so if the styles would not be applied than I would noticed it for sure. Anyway, I've tried your suggestion. It did not help...

Comment: @Wodzu, Just look at the generated markup and use firebug (or similar tool) and you should be able to find your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a standard place holder (not a content one). then in your master page figuring out which page is being requested and putting in a  yourself?

Comment: I am sorry I am afraid that I don't understand what are you saying...Do you suggest that I should detect on Page_Load event what page is requested and include the css file in codebehind?

Comment: yes, that is what I'm saying. If I am understanding you correctly, you want a MyContentPage.css included, so for each content page you can have a seperate css file. So, putting a little bit of code into the code behind for the master page should work.

Comment: I can include MyContentPage.css in the given content's page "head" ContentPlaceHolder and this works fine. Maybe I should not mention content pages at all, just look my example. It is simple and it does not work...

Comment: ah, okay - i see what you're getting at now. The paths to the css files are relative. Have you tried using the tilde character? ie - ~/Stylesheets/MyContentPage.css

Comment: I've tried that also... Strange, I've closed and reopen Visual Studio and now it works! Sorry for wasting your time, and thanks for trying to help me:)